# What is the delegate method for Ios Google maps for did finish scrolling?

Tags: ios, ios5, google-maps-sdk-ios

In Apple maps there is a delegate method

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

and is fired when I end scrolling or panning the map but I could not find such method for google maps.
There is a method

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
```

but this method keeps on firing while the map is still being scrolled and I don't want that.  I have to change a property only when scrolling is finished.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The latest SDK release Version 1.4.0 - July 2013 has added a new delegate method

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position
```

that will be triggered at the end of any camera movement or scrolling action

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request to add something like this:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4722

In the meantime you could perhaps work around it by using a regular timer which checks if the map position has changed since the last call to the timer. If not then the user has stopped moving the map and so you can update your property.

Answer (score 0):

Beware idleAtCameraPosition is when map stops moving not when you lift your finger.

And as of Google sdk iOS 1.7 I noticed it gets triggered early even when you still have the finger on the map.

So if you're using it to redraw overlays/markers it may happen too early and cause stuttering.

I had to subclass GSMapView and add PanGestureRecognizer >> State ENDED to get when finger lifted.

see
https://github.com/clearbrian/GoogleMapiOS_TapEndedGesture